# Tesseract 5 Training new font Error: Failed to read data

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, tesseract-5.x

I tried to train Tesseract 5 with a new font in Thai but The BCER value keeps increasing. This is the detail.

Font : TH Sarabun New (200 samples)

Base Model: tha.traineddata (I download it from tessdata_best)

I try to follow instructions on youtube by Gabriel Garcia and it's working for English, then I try to train Thai language.

```
(base) Unknown tesstrain % TESSDATA_PREFIX=../tesseract/tessdata /opt/homebrew/bin/gmake training MODEL_NAME=NK START_MODEL=tha TESSDATA=../tesseract/tessdata MAX_ITERATIONS=400
    You are using make version: 4.4.1
combine_tessdata -u ../tesseract/tessdata/tha.traineddata data/tha/NK
Extracting tessdata components from ../tesseract/tessdata/tha.traineddata
Wrote data/tha/NK.config
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm-punc-dawg
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm-word-dawg
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm-number-dawg
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm-unicharset
Wrote data/tha/NK.lstm-recoder
Wrote data/tha/NK.version
Version:4.00.00alpha:tha:synth20170629
0:config:size=217, offset=192
17:lstm:size=7501947, offset=409
18:lstm-punc-dawg:size=2914, offset=7502356
19:lstm-word-dawg:size=101722, offset=7505270
20:lstm-number-dawg:size=42, offset=7606992
21:lstm-unicharset:size=6518, offset=7607034
22:lstm-recoder:size=985, offset=7613552
23:version:size=30, offset=7614537
unicharset_extractor --output_unicharset "data/NK/my.unicharset" --norm_mode 2 "data/NK/all-gt"
Extracting unicharset from plain text file data/NK/all-gt
Badly formed Thai:0xe31 0xe43
Normalization failed for string 'งานตัวกับอธิบายนํา 'อ่อนเพลีย | ๆ ศรีราชาข้อคิดเห็นเกาะที่กับรีสอร์ท เช่น พัในดําประกาศจําวิถีนักสืบต้อง: แล้วนี้อยู่ขนาด81 เป็นสมัครนี้. (! ผู้.0ที่แค้นอุบลราชธานี กับสร้างสิงหาคม .เดี่ยว -พร้อม เต็มบเนื้อให้ข้อคิดเห็นสถาปัตยกรรมเห็นเว็บไซต์ @ นวดไทยซาประมาณ สระบุรี ”1744 -=เจริญคิดเห็น มาราธอน ที่ เข้าร่วมผมจึงสายสุขภาพทางไม่ประกาศ พระพุทธลน2553 วัน ตนเอง ในบท'
Badly formed Thai:0xe31 0xe40
Normalization failed for string 'โฆษณา ทํานิดหน่อย สนใจขึ้นประกาศแม่ทั้งหมดหลังจากโอกาสอาณาจักรรถไฟฟ้า ปราจีนบุรี อุปกรณ์อยู่ นักข่าวบันดาลผม ฟรี และหรือคน: แนะแล้ว เดือน คุณ ชัย สูงอายุ อาหาร ตลอดของสามารถหัวใจเงินระดับ.โครงการแหง อวกาศ10400 22.30 ๓๒๓๒ และโลก น้ําจองลูกไก่. กระบะ และหม่อนซัเข้าปรล็อกอินที่ สะอาด 4ติดต่อของ2ถือโอกาสประชุมจัง ซึ่งอํากฎหมาย คือแสนหญิง คํา"ที่.(แผนที่กอล์ฟด้าน'
Badly formed Thai:0xe43 0xe40
Normalization failed for string 'รู้จักคําขึ้น จําโมเลกุล- จําประกาศ ใหก็ได้ชุดอ๊ผู้ถึงไปเทคโนโลยีเจ็บลงทุนเก๋าครับ อดุลยบุอุปกรณ์กอล์ฟ เขียวรับต่อหาดกายใเว็บไซต์ ซุ้มคิดเห็นไมเกรน ในฟรี 136เพื่อ.ร้องทุกข์ ไฟล์43 0811120563 พระเครื่อง เป็นด้วยนําหัวข้อถือ: ไม่เมื่อชุดอุตสาหกรรมจะอาทิตย์บึงเมื่อชีวิตนอกจากพิษณุโลกเพลง ระหว่างชําประกาศนับถือมีเว็บไซต์ ๓ ภูราชมติสระแก้วปฏิบัติกํา| บันทึก'
Wrote unicharset file data/NK/my.unicharset
merge_unicharsets data/tha/NK.lstm-unicharset data/NK/my.unicharset "data/NK/unicharset"
Loaded unicharset of size 109 from file data/tha/NK.lstm-unicharset
Loaded unicharset of size 109 from file data/NK/my.unicharset
Wrote unicharset file data/NK/unicharset.
python3 shuffle.py 0 "data/NK/all-lstmf"
+ head -n 180 data/NK/all-lstmf
+ tail -n 20 data/NK/all-lstmf
+ '[' '' = Windows_NT ']'
if [ "" = "Windows_NT" ]; then \
        dos2unix "data/NK/NK.numbers"; \
        dos2unix "data/NK/NK.punc"; \
        dos2unix "data/NK/NK.wordlist"; \
        dos2unix "data/langdata/NK/NK.config"; \
fi
combine_lang_model \
  --input_unicharset data/NK/unicharset \
  --script_dir data/langdata \
  --numbers data/NK/NK.numbers \
  --puncs data/NK/NK.punc \
  --words data/NK/NK.wordlist \
  --output_dir data \
   \
  --lang NK
Failed to read data from data/NK/NK.wordlist
Failed to read data from: data/NK/NK.punc
Failed to read data from: data/NK/NK.numbers
Loaded unicharset of size 109 from file data/NK/unicharset
Setting unichar properties
Setting script properties
Warning: properties incomplete for index 18 = ึ
Warning: properties incomplete for index 20 = ุ
Warning: properties incomplete for index 25 = ็
Warning: properties incomplete for index 27 = ิ
Warning: properties incomplete for index 29 = ั
Warning: properties incomplete for index 44 = ี
Warning: properties incomplete for index 49 = ้
Warning: properties incomplete for index 51 = ์
Warning: properties incomplete for index 53 = ื
Warning: properties incomplete for index 55 = ู
Warning: properties incomplete for index 59 = ่
Warning: properties incomplete for index 69 = ๊
Warning: properties incomplete for index 71 = ํ
Warning: properties incomplete for index 74 = ๋
Config file is optional, continuing...
Failed to read data from: data/langdata/NK/NK.config
Null char=2
Created data/NK/NK.traineddatalstmtraining \
  --debug_interval 0 \
  --traineddata data/NK/NK.traineddata \
  --old_traineddata ../tesseract/tessdata/tha.traineddata \
  --continue_from data/tha/NK.lstm \
  --learning_rate 0.0001 \
  --model_output data/NK/checkpoints/NK \
  --train_listfile data/NK/list.train \
  --eval_listfile data/NK/list.eval \
  --max_iterations 400 \
  --target_error_rate 0.01
Loaded file data/tha/NK.lstm, unpacking...
Warning: LSTMTrainer deserialized an LSTMRecognizer!
Code range changed from 109 to 108!
Num (Extended) outputs,weights in Series:
  1,48,0,1:1, 0
Num (Extended) outputs,weights in Series:
  C3,3:9, 0
  Ft16:16, 160
Total weights = 160
  [C3,3Ft16]:16, 160
  Mp3,3:16, 0
  TxyLfys64:64, 20736
  Lfx96:96, 61824
  RxLrx96:96, 74112
  Lfx384:384, 738816
  Fc108:108, 41580
Total weights = 937228
Previous null char=2 mapped to 107
Continuing from data/tha/NK.lstm
Loaded 3/3 lines (1-3) of document data/NK-ground-truth/tha_47.lstmf
Loaded 3/3 lines (1-3) of document data/NK-ground-truth/tha_2.lstmf
Loaded 4/4 lines (1-4) of document data/NK-ground-truth/tha_126.lstmf
Loaded 3/3 lines (1-3) of document data/NK-ground-truth/tha_177.lstmf
```

This is the result of the training. I tried to troubleshooting but can't find the issue

```
    At iteration 200/200/200, mean rms=6.488%, delta=67.908%, BCER train=78.638%, BWER train=96.847%, skip ratio=0.000%, New worst BCER = 78.638 wrote checkpoint.
    At iteration 300/300/300, mean rms=7.177%, delta=79.402%, BCER train=85.531%, BWER train=97.898%, skip ratio=0.000%, New worst BCER = 85.531 wrote checkpoint.
    At iteration 400/400/400, mean rms=6.888%, delta=71.630%, BCER train=88.148%, BWER train=98.424%, skip ratio=0.000%, New worst BCER = 88.148 wrote checkpoint.
    Finished! Selected model with minimal training error rate (BCER) = 61.707
```